Vue Devtool tips in React Project
I'm developing React project within Vite, but started to get tips for Vue Dev Tool in web-browser console:

What is the way to remove these tips?
There are some options to disable it through Vue-config file, but it's related only to Vue-projects. So don't have an idea what to do?!

This is weird behavior. If you have a Vue Dev Tool extension installed, you might want to disable it. If you still get this issue, you should post on the Vue dev tool repository
